# Unable to do a cakephp edit due to nginx error

Tags: nginx, cakephp-2.3

I have a CakePHP application which runs on nginx. Unfortunately it gives an error which i find it hard to debug due to its vagueness

```
2014/12/21 16:29:01 [crit] 6451#0: *5 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000002" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 220.255.1.150, server: localhost, request: "POST /announcements/edit/60004 HTTP/1.1", host: "tmkr-cms.gumi.sg", referrer: "http://tmkr-cms.gumi.sg/announcements/edit/60004"
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: It says the directory `/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000002` cannot be accessed by nginx. Check accesses for the nginx user on each one of the dirs up to `000...2`

Comment: which directory you are talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000002" failed (13: Permission denied

chmod +x /var/lib/nginx -R

Answer (score 0):

In my case the cause of this problem was the size of the buffer (header and body).

Edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add:

```
...
client_body_buffer_size 2m;
client_header_buffer_size 10k;
client_max_body_size 8m;
large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
...
```

Hope will help!